# Limit points of infinite subsets of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Is the following statement true or false?

> If $F$ is an infinite subset of a closed set $E$, then $F$ has a limit point in $E$?

The original one is: if $E$ is an infinite subset of a *compact* set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$. This statement is proved in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. However, I just use the closing property of $K$ in my proof, so I'm not sure of the statemet above.

Comment: What about if you consider $\mathbb N \subset [0, \infty)$, where all are considered as subspaces of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology?

Answer (score 1):

Compactness is key. For the real line, keep in mind the Heine-Borel theorem which says a set is compact iff it is closed *and* bounded. As a counterexample then, take an unbounded closed set  $\mathbb{R}$ (in the space $\mathbb{R}$), and take $\mathbb{Z}$.